# Как узнать url файла php?

Tags: php, android

Я делаю регистрация в своем андроид приложении,и мне нужно обратиться к php-файлу на хостинге,но я не знаю как узнать url к этому файлу.

Comment: у вас доступ к этому хостингу есть? домен знаете, которыый привязан к этому хостингу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo 'путь от корневой папки: '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'<br>';
    echo 'Полный путь к скрипту и его имя: '.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'].'<br>';
    echo 'Имя скрипта: '.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
?>
```

Comment: Кажись `__FILE__` решает задачу.

Comment: на сколько я помню _FILE_ и '$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']'  это одно и тоже

Comment: @AseTry - нет конечно, это разные вещи.. DOCUMENT_ROOT -путь к корневой директории сервера

Comment: ну я забросил PhP давненько поэтому не помню. :)]

Answer (score 3):

В данном php файле вставьте этот код `<?php echo __FILE__; ?>`   после запуска php файла в нём покажет полный путь.

Comment: @merey nabi Рекомендую прочитать про роутинг запросов. Как правильно связать адреса с запросами и т. д., старайтесь избегать открытых запросов. И желательно сделать единую точку входа `index.php` и слать все запросы на `index.php`, с нужным маршрутом.